# Reprinting error outside function call in python

Tags: python, error-handling

I am fairly new to python and trying to handle an error that allows me to display the two points that cause failure. One variable is within a function and the other variable is outside of the function. My attempt is the code below:

```
def fun(x):
    z = 0.5 * x
    if z == 1.0:
        return z
    else:
        raise Exception('z is not 1.0')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    y = 9.0
    x = y / 4.0
    try:
        print fun(x)
    except fun as err:
        print 'y is %f' % y
        print err
```

So if `y = 8.0`, then `x = 2.0` and `z = 1.0` and I'm good. But if `y = 9.0` then `z != 10` and I want the error and the value of `y` to be displayed. `y` is not accessible within `fun()`, so I can do it in there.

I realize that this is a pointless example. In reality I'm passing a row of data from a file to `fun()`, and I want `fun()` to throw the error on which part of the row causes the error, but it doesn't know the file name.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use your outside `try/except` to catch and respond to the expected `Exception` within `fun()`.

You basically had it, just need to change `except fun as err:` to `except Exception as err:`

```
def fun(x):
    z = 0.5 * x
    if z == 1.0:
        return z
    else:
        raise Exception('z is not 1.0')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    y = 9.0
    x = y / 4.0
    try:
        print fun(x)
    except Exception as err:
        print 'y is %f' % y
        print err
```

Comment: But the function does not have access to the variable y. I would like to be able for the user to know the value of y and z that caused the error. Unless I'm misunderstanding.

Comment: Can you rewrite your example to be more like your production code? Right now the `try/except` line *does* have access to the `y` variable. Even though `fun()` is a separate function, it only raises the `Exception`. The `try/except` is the code running, catching and reporting on the error raised by `fun()`.

Comment: Okay thanks. I see that I'm being confusing. You are 100% right. I didn't realize that you actually edited the code and fully answered my question. I needed Exception in the except line. That's what I couldn't figure out. Thanks!